# Stopping a screen crack from spreading?

Tags: display, hardware-failure, lcd

I have a late 2011 15" Macbook Pro (though I think my question is more general). I just noticed a small and fairly superficial crack on the glass covering the LCD -- there is no damage to the LCD at the moment. The problem is that since I've noticed the crack it has spread a bit (it's currently about 1.5").

I've seen/heard of people using clear nail polish to patch up windshields (e.g., http://www.ehow.com/how_12152219_seal-windshield-cracks-fingernail-polish.html). Does this work? Are there any tricks to stop a screen crack from spreading?

Comment: Just be careful with it.  Use two hands to open and close the lid and apply smooth pressure as you do so.  Don't put any weight on the display.  In truth, the best you can do is just hope that it'll last a while - there's really no stopping it in the long run.

Comment: In the long run, it'll be a long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried talking to an Apple shop? They can be very good sometimes at fixing things for you - part of the service you pay for when you buy Apple. Always worth a try.

Ultimately, nothing will stop it spreading. However, since you really have nothing to loose at this point, you could try some "superglue" or similar cyanoacrylate based product. Put a small amount along the crack and very gently wipe any excess away. When wiping, do so along the crack towards the nearest edge to try and avoid getting any onto undamaged screen areas. Breathing on the crack before applying the glue will help it set slightly faster (the moisture activates the glue).

You could also try applying (very gently) some transparent tape. You can get highly transparent tape from stationary suppliers that is designed for repairing torn documents.

Neither of these will be a permanent fix so you might want to investigate the best cost route for a screen replacement.

It goes without saying that the more you move the screen the more likely it is to spread the crack.